# How to update a client secret of an Azure B2C OpenId Connect programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup an OpenID Connect provider using Azure B2C to enable my iOS users to sign in my application using `Sign-in with Apple`.

I followed [the instructions](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) and it is working great.

I have to update [the token regularly](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) and I am trying to automate it.

I have set up an Azure Function that will be triggered on a schedule and it generates a new token.

Now I do not know how to update the client secret from the Azure Function itself. I am not sure [which](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/identityprovider/update) to use...

[image]

**Question**

How can I update the client secret field of the external provider I have set up?

**Update**

The [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityprovider-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) seems to be what I need but I do not know how to reconcile a user and the configuration of an Azure AD B2C service ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the client secret with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityprovider-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp). See the  [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/tree/master/#key-concepts) about calling the Microsoft Graph API.

```
// Read application settings from appsettings.json (tenant ID, app ID, client secret, etc.)
AppSettings config = AppSettingsFile.ReadFromJsonFile();

// Initialize the client credential auth provider
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.AppId)
    .WithTenantId(config.TenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(config.AppSecret)
    .Build();
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

// Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

// call Update identityProvider API
var identityProvider = new IdentityProvider
{
    ClientSecret = "1111111111111"
};

await graphClient.IdentityProviders["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(identityProvider);
```